# Join three tables with group by giving error

Tags: mysql, database, join, group-by, sql-order-by

There are three tables in the database `users`, `organization_entries` and `user_invoices` and I am trying to Join these three tables and my query is somewhat like this

`select users.id , sum(user_invoices.due_amount) , organization_entries.id, organization_entries.createdAt  from users INNER JOIN user_invoices ON users.id = user_invoices.customer_id INNER JOIN on users.id = organization_entries.user_id GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY organization_entries.createdAt`;

But again and again, I am getting this error -

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on users.id = organization_entries.user_id GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY organiza' at line 1
```

I am not able to understand where I am doing things wrong.

Comment: missing table name at `INNER JOIN on users.id = organization_entries.user_id`

Comment: Yes silly mistake thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the query as follows, you are missing table in second inner join

```
select users.id , sum(user_invoices.due_amount) , organization_entries.id, 
organization_entries.createdAt 
from users INNER JOIN user_invoices ON users.id = user_invoices.customer_id 
INNER JOIN organization_entries ON users.id = organization_entries.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY organization_entries.createdAt ;
```